# Add dynamic link to listview webpart in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint webpage with custom Listview webpart that displays a list of links from a SharePoint List. I have created a Jquery to pull URL and displayName from JSON with POST method. Now the challenge is how to add these dynamic URL and displayName as anchor in the list with alphabetically sorted place under a specific list group in the listview webpart?

Listview webpart will be like this:

```
Application1
       Link1
       Link2
Application2
       Link3
Application3
Application4
       Link4
       Link5
       Link6
       Link8
```

All Application are collapsible expandable view of the list.
Please help add a link say `Link7` under `Application4` between `Link6` and `Link8`.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JSLink to render view

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(options)
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views